# Value of $x=z+z^2+z^4$ where $z=e^\frac{2πi}{7}$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $z=e^\frac{2πi}{7}$ and let $x=z+z^2+z^4$.Then

$1.$ $x\in \Bbb Q$.

$2.$ $x\in \Bbb Q(\sqrt {D})$  for some $D \gt 0$.

$3.$ $x\in \Bbb Q(\sqrt {D})$  for some $D \lt 0$.

$4.$ $x\in i\Bbb R$.

Here $z$ is seventh root of unity.Hence $1+z+z^2+z^3+z^4+z^5+z^6=0$ hence
$z^2+z^4+z=-1-z^3-z^5-z^6$.$z^2$ and $z^4$ are conjugate of each other.hence their addition will be some real no.similarly for $z^3$ and $z^5$.But how to proceed further?

Comment: Investigate $x+\overline x$ and $x-\overline x$.

Comment: Also, you can try and write $x^2$ in terms of $x$ and $1$. Using that degree six minimal polynomial. I have answered this question on our site in another context (I'm sure many others have done the same), but posting a link would amount to blowing my own trumpet I think.

Comment: @Jyrki :I got $1+x+x^2=0$.hence option 3 is correct.Am I correct?

Comment: Also, $$x\cdot \bar x$$

Comment: Check the calculation! It should be $x^2+x+2=0$. Anyway, yes, option (3) is correct. It may actually be simpler to use the hints of Lord Shark the Unknown and Lab Bhattacharjee, and calculate the polynomial $$(X-x)(X-\overline{x})=X^2+X+2.$$ The sum $x$ is a zero of this, and the quadratic formula does the rest.

Comment: Look up [Gauss sums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_Gauss_sum) for more information.